# Permanently change symbol of itemize

Tags: itemize

I am aware one can *locally* change the symbol of itemize by adding an option to `\item`, like:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\uparrow$] some item
\end{itemize}
```

Is there a way to set *permanently* the symbol of `itemize`, for instance by redefining a command?

Something like

```
\setitemizesymbol{$\uparrow$]
\begin{itemize}
\item some item
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy if you load the `enumitem` package, adding this code in your preamble:

```
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\uparrow$}
```

The number `1` (second argument) denotes the  level of the environment. Here, it is not nested in another itemize.

Answer (score 6):

For the four supported levels of nesting, the labels output by the `itemize` environment of the LaTeX kernel are produced by `\labelitemi`, `\labelitemii`, `\labelitemiii` and `\labelitemiv`. You can redefine these macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\labelitemfont\textasteriskcentered}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\labelitemfont\textendash}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\labelitemfont\textbf{\textdagger}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{%
  \labelitemfont\textbf{:\kern 1.5pt -\raisebox{-0.1ex}[0pt][0pt]{)}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item foo1
  \begin{itemize}
  \item foo2
  \item bar2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item foo3
    \item bar3
    \item baz3
      \begin{itemize}
      \item foo4
      \item bar4
      \item baz4
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\item bar1
\item baz1
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]